# I want to create login in laravel, and have problem in cmd with: php artisan make:auth

Tags: php, html, laravel

When I run this command: `php artisan make:auth`

I get an error:

> command "make:auth" is not defined.

[image]

I have a problem in command with `php artisan make:auth`. How can I create a login in laravel

Comment: run `php artisan --version` If it's `>= 6` then as @salaman-zafar said, `make:auth` is no longer in the default install of version 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artisan command "make:auth" is not defined in Laravel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774231/artisan-command-makeauth-is-not-defined-in-laravel-6)

Comment: the laravel version is 6.0.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Laravel 6 `auth` command has been removed and authentication scaffolding has been moved as separate package named `laravel/ui`

Here you can read about [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/releases) and [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) and also here you can read about `laravel/ui` in laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/frontend)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 6.0 has removed this command:`php artisan make:auth`

**Update for Laravel 6:** The command to implement Auth is as follows:

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

This command will install a layout view, **registration** and **login views**, as well as routes for all authentication end-points. A HomeController will also be generated

---

**NOTE:** If your login page only shows plain HTML. And CSS is not loading properly then run this two command:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```